# How to reassure someone who is saying sorry for their mistake

Tags: sentence-construction, politeness

What can I tell someone who is saying sorry for their mistake?

1. > Why you are saying sorry for this?
2. > Why you are telling me sorry for this?
3. > Sometimes it happens to me too.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi. Do you have to use the word "sorry"? In that type of conversation, many adult native-spaekers would probably use "apologize" (American-English, apologise Commonwealth-English). But you can use "sorry" if that really is the word you want to use. Let me know and so I can draft and answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "speak like convincing someone who is telling..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are seeking to reassure someone who is apologising to you. They are saying "sorry for ..." and you want to make sure that they understand that you do not see them as being at fault, they really have no need to apologise; you want them to understand that your are not offended.

First, it is nice that someone apologises to you, and I think it's important that we acknowledge that they care; we don't want to dismiss their politeness. So we start by:

> Thanks Bill,

Then we want to reassure them that we are not offended.

> but there's no need to apologise. Honestly it's not a problem, that could have happened to anyone.

In less formal situations we might just say:

> Thanks Bill, no problem. Forget about it.

The "no problem" is an increasingly common idiom. Australians might well say the equivalent:

> No Worries mate.

Comment: I like this "you are seeking to reassure someone who is apologising to you." upVoted!